# how to make a vector synchronized such that from two threads only one thread will access it

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In My Program there are two classes A and B, both of them extend Thread, Now B has a Queue named CommandQueue. Now Thread B access it until it becomes empty and Class A thread access it whenever found new commands to insert in it. How can I make this queue synchronized such that at a time both thread can not access it, and when one has used this queue, make it free to be used by another thread.  Also please suggest if there will not be any problem in case I do not make it synchronized.

Comment: You mentioned Vector in your question title. Vectors are already synchronized.

Comment: actually I want that in order, thread A insert the commands in the dataStructure (either vector or any other), THread B should also access it in that order and remove that like a queue works

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to `extend Thread` directly. You should implement Runnable and wrap it with a Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to use Threads and queues together to perform work, it is highly likely that an ExecutorService is the best choice.  This is because they are designed to wrap up both of these concepts.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.new (pick a thread pool of your choice)

// in thread A
es.execute(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // task to run on Thread B
   }
});

// in thread A
Future<Type> future = es.submit(new Callable<Type>() {
   public Type call() {
      // task to run on Thread B and ...
      return type;
   }
});

// later get the result
Type t = future.get();
```

Note: you don't have to refer to the queue or thread pool directly, all you need is to say what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you need a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instead of plain Vector.

BlockingQueue.put(E e): Inserts the specified element into this queue, waiting if necessary for space to become available.

BlockingQueue.take(): Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

Comment: how to instantiate a BlockingQueue, mean which DataStructure type Object It can hold

Comment: Any type. BlockingQueue is generic collection which can be defines as BlockingQueue<MyCommand> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<MyCommand>();

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear whether the code uses Vector or a Queue. If its Vector then its always synchronized, this problem is very similar to the Producer-Consumer problem. It might help if you look into that

Comment: so is it mean if two different threads of different classes will access the same vector object then since vector is synchronized so it will not create problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either: ConcurrentLinkedQueue or other collection with wait/notify.

I. ConcurrentLinkedQueue

```
  ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object> myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object>();

  ...
  // first thread
  myQueue.add(someObject);

  ...
  // seconds thread
  Object someObject = myQueue.poll()
```

II. Wait/Notify

Code just for example. You'll need to handle exception and read about thread wake-up issue.

```
  ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

  ...    
  // first thread
  synchronized(objects) {
      objects.add(someObject);
      objects.notifyAll();
  }

  ...
  // second thread
  synchronized(objects) {
      objects.wait();
      for (Object someObject: objects) {
          // do something with someObject
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just synchronize the Threads by adding "synchronized".

```
public void synchronized Producer(Object whatever) {
    // Insert into the Queue here
     Queue.add(whatever);
}

public Object synchronized Consumer() {
    // Get Values out of the Queue here
    Queue.remove(whatever);
}
```

Just call the functions, where you need it, and everything will run fine and "fully synched" :)